# TypeError: ModelName.forge(...).destroy is not a function

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, bookshelf.js, sinon-chai

I'm working on a API using node, where ModelName means the model built using bookshelf.js like this:

```
const bookshelf = require('./bookshelf')
const Intake = require('./intake')

const ModelName = bookshelf.Model.extend(
    {
        tableName: 'modelName',
        hasTimestamps: true,
        uuid: true,
        otherModel: function() {
            return this.hasOne(OtherModel)
        }
    },
    {
        dependents: ['otherModel']
    }
)

module.exports = ModelName
```

and when testing the following funtion:

```
deleteModelName(Id) {
            try {
                return ModelName.forge({ id: Id }).destroy()
            } catch (err) {
                Logger.error('ModelNameService#deleteModelName :: failed to delete ModelName', > err.stack) 
             throw err
              }
            }
```

With this test:

> ```
> describe('#deleteModelName', () => {
>     it('should call deleteModelName', async () => {
>            /*Creating a ModelName*/
>
>         const deleteModelName = sandbox.stub()
>         deleteModelName.resolves(CreatedModelName)
>         const result = await ModelNameService.deleteModelName(ModelName.id)
>         expect(result).to.be.undefined }}
> ```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: ModelName.forge(...).destroy is not a function
```

Comment: what is CreatedModelName, ModelNameService and ModelName in your test file? please add imports too. btw you are not using the stub you create, its useless right now.

Comment: You didn't use `deleteModelName` stub. Where does `ModelName` object come from? Please includes the codes